# How shall I automatically accept the permission prompts in Ginger by Amdocs?

Tags: selenium-chromedriver, ui-automation, user-permissions

I am trying to automate a site which asks for some permissions from user like location, notification, camera, microphone. I want to allow access for these permissions from Ginger by Amdocs actions/activity. I am unable to locate that permission prompt from Ginger By Amdocs.

I guess for this I might need to run JavaScript or Selenium Script from Ginger By Amdocs. Please guide me with the correct steps of it.